# Selecting and manipulating multiple sliders at once

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have this idea in my head for an equalizer-like control, but I'd like to be able to do multiselection of the various thumbs and move them all at once. I thought of using a listbox and using the selection property it has but I haven't quite worked out how I'd be able to pass that down into the sliders and move them all in unison. Does anyone have any good ideas or has seen something like this done before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you have some control that the user interacts with. One idea would be to create adorners around those controls to show "selected" state. Listen in on the mouse clicks for each of those controls and test the Ctrl modifier (Ctrl and/or shift, both are commonly used for multiple selection). Toggle the selected state of each of them which you'll store in a separate collection (an array perhaps).

When you detect movement on one of these controls, check to see if it's selected. If it is, move all the others.

Comment: I like this idea but I'm not sure if I'll go down this path simply because the slider class provides a lot of that functionality up front. Maybe I can take your ideas though and add to the slider class to come up with a solution like you've described.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use the SelectedItems property of the Listbox in MultiExtended selection mode.

you bind it to an Observablecollection

then you check the slider's valueChanged event and in the eventhandler you get the difference and increment all the sliders' values in the collection.

now when you select and drag a slider's thumb it will affect other selected sliders.

(minor question: are you using MVVM?)

Comment: This was the path I first thought of using. I am not using MVVM simply because I haven't learned enough about it yet... (My WPF books don't talk about it), but I use the concepts at least loosely. Binding, separation of UI and the logic behind it, etc are all major parts of my designs so far. I like this idea but I'm going to wait to award points until I've tried each design.

Comment: forget about my idea and try Tergiver's instead.
My solution implies to directly select the slider, whereas you can't select a slider without impacting on the slider's value and the slider captures the mouse so you can't do multi-selection.
With Tergiver's you check the ardoner's state so it would work